# Why do some posts get deleted by Community with only a few flags?

Tags: support, rude-or-abusive

I recently encountered a post that was locked by the Community user as spam or offensive. However, its score was only -3. Why did it get deleted with that few of flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes a moderator happens to walk by just in time to smite the post out of existence before enough regular users can pile on their regular flags. Moderators' spam and rude/abusive flags are always binding (and equally binding to reverse should a mistake be made).

Comment: Why does it show as being deleted by community rather than by a mod? Did they apply the hard flag?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Posts that are deleted as spam or rude/abusive are always shown as locked and deleted by Community.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the moderator flagged the post too or if they accepted the flag through a review queue or something? If a mod rude/abusive/spam flagged a post, it would be gone right away, right?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: It does. Accepting a red flag doesn't cause it to be deleted or the rep penalty to be applied. The post must either reach 6 regular flags (whether or not they have been approved doesn't matter IIRC, but *not* declined or disputed), or be flagged directly by a mod, for those effects to be applied, which results in them all being approved.

Comment: So, in this case a moderator nuked the post by casting the third red flag?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Yes.

Comment: not only posts closed by moderators, [posts closed when the askers agreed that they are duplicates will be shown as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253016/230282)

Comment: @phuclv: Did you comment on the wrong answer by mistake? This one isn't about closing questions. It's about posts getting deleted via rude/abusive flags.

Comment: yes. Just realized that it's not about duplicates